# connected sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: general-topology

$n\mathbb{RP}^2$ is $2n$-gon with identified edges.
Can you check directions of arrows in picture?
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Except for maybe the part where it says "$2n$-gow." :)

Comment: Yes, all of the arrows have the same orientation